# How to connect to a MS Access file (mdb) using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to connect to a mdb file and I understand that I would need `Microsoft.OLEDB.JET.4.0` data provider. Unfortunately, I do not have it installed on the (University) machine.
Since, they don't provide that provider, I believe there should be a way around.

How can I connect to the file without `Microsoft.OLEDB.JET.4.0` or is there any alternative ?

I have following providers:

[image: Available Ole DB providers]

I have tried using `OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services`, to which while testing connection, I get 'Test succeeded but some settings were not accepted by the provider'. I took that string and used it anyway and I got `ADsDSOObject' failed with no error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND(0x80040E14)`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way to connect is through an OdbcConnection using code like this

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

using(OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection())
{
    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    //execute queries, etc

}
```

where myConnectionString is something like this

```
myConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" + 
"Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

See [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007)

In alternative you could create a DSN and then use that DSN in your connection string

- Open the Control Panel - Administrative Tools - ODBC Data Source
  Manager
- Go to the System DSN Page and ADD a new DSN
- Choose the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) and press END
- Set the Name of the DSN (choose MyDSN for this example)
- Select the Database to be used
- Try the Compact or Recover commands to see if the connection works

now your connectionString could be written in this way

```
myConnectionString = "DSN=myDSN;"
```

Comment: Thanks `OdbcConnection` did it.

Comment: when MDW is in picture, you can need different connection string. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307822/426315)

Comment: Pretty good answer, you can also take a look to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430415/entity-framework-with-microsoft-access) to check how to use Microsoft Access with Entity Framewor.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to use a Jet OLEDB or Ace OLEDB Access DB:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                           "Data Source=C:\myPath\myFile.mdb;" +                                    
                           "Persist Security Info=True;" +
                           "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=myPassword;";
try
{
    // Open OleDb Connection
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    // Execute Queries
    OleDbCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `myTable`";
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); // close conn after complete

    // Load the result into a DataTable
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
    myDataTable.Load(reader);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OLEDB Connection FAILED: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Very helpful and worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You should use "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers" to get to access to Microsoft Access. Here is the sample tutorial on using it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That gave me: `Test Connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Data source name not found and no default driver specified.`. Do you think this provider does not exist?

Comment: Please refer this link for available connection strings

http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 3):

What Access File extension or you using? The Jet OLEDB or the Ace OLEDB.
If your Access DB is .mdb (aka Jet Oledb)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Oledb

namespace MembershipInformationSystem.Helpers
{
    public class dbs
    {
        private String connectionString;
        private String OleDBProvider = "Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0"; \\if ACE Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
        private String OleDBDataSource = "C:\\yourdb.mdb";
        private String OleDBPassword = "infosys";
        private String PersistSecurityInfo = "False";

        public dbs()
        {

        }

        public dbs(String connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public String konek()
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=" + OleDBProvider + ";Data Source=" + OleDBDataSource + ";JET OLEDB:Database Password=" + OleDBPassword + ";Persist Security Info=" + PersistSecurityInfo + "";
            return connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the OleDbConnectionStringBuilder class the better solution?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

OleDbConnection dbConn;

dConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Registration.accdb;");
```

Comment: If you are using MS Access 2010

Answer (score 0):

Another simplest way to connect is through an **OdbcConnection** using **App.config** file like this

```
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="Conn" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"/>
  </appSettings>
```

MyDB.mdb is my database file and it is present in current primary application folder with main exe file.

if your mdf file has password then use like this

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Conn" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Admin$@123"/>
  </appSettings>
```