# How to create ODBC Connection to Access database with code in C# 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I am trying to connect to an Access DB using odbcConnection through ConnectionString in Properties menu in VS C# 2010 Express version.
I get an error that tells me this option isn't enable in Express edition and I am forced to use other versions or code.

How I can use code for do this connection?

Comment: Have u gone through this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Data.Odbc;

using(OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection())
{
    var myConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" + 
        "Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;";
    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    //execute queries, etc
}
```

See [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/)

Reproduced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c).

Comment: Q+1, A+1, Thank god, there are answers that give me exactly what I need.