# C# Database Issues with connection

Tags: c#, database

Something seems wrong with the c# database for Accounts:

Right at the database I get the error message of:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Connection' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I possibly doing wrong with it? I would like to connect to the database in the Accounts

http://puu.sh/hiYKZ/01e0da1578.png

**code:-**

```
    public SQLConnection acctsConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }

        SQLConnection connect = null;

        try{
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("C:\\ChattBankMDB.mdb");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }

        return connect;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post only relevant code

Comment: Sorry Kyle, here is the relevant code to the issue I'm having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could pass for valid c# code but the APIs you are using are wrong ... which leads me to believe it is valid java code ... database code in c# would use `ADO.NET` (`SQLConnection`, `Command` etc) but you are using `Connection`, `Statement` etc .. which are consistent with `JDBC`

Please review what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I've taken Java for 3 semesters and should have known that was the issue (new to c#) it did not give me complete errors therefore I figured it was right.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass sqlconnection in your code and write your database path in data source.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TCS3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Forest_DB;User ID=sa;Password=sql2008");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is using ms sql server instead of access file format
but your answer is:
[How to connect to a MS Access file (mdb) using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c)