# Updating the value(s) in an MS Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to set up a system that allows the user to alter the values of stock in an MS Access database. It is supposed to update the stock value of the SKU that has been entered on a previous form. Instead I don't get any error message, the program just sits there and doesn't do anything. The record does not get updated, no exceptions are thrown and I'm 99% certain the connection string is valid.

I had set it up so that once the operation is complete, it notified the user with a popup but this doesn't display either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace InventoryManager
{
    public partial class frmAdjustment : Form
    {
        frmAmendStock _main;

        public string enteredSKU { get; set; }

        public frmAdjustment(frmAmendStock main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _main = main;
        }        

        private void frmAdjustment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = btnSubmit;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection())
            {

                connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Other\Documents\University Work\USB\Individual Project\Artefact\InventoryManager\InventoryManager\stock.mdb";
                connect.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE items SET Stock = @stock, Stock_Counted = @counted WHERE SKU ='" +enteredSKU+"'", connect);
                string units = txtAmount.Text;

                    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(units))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct amount of units.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stock", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@counted", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;

                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("Stock Adjusted", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                                txtAmount.Clear();

                                connect.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception expe)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
                                connect.Close();
                            }
                      }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After updating the code I now get this error:

[image: Microsoft JET Database Engine error]

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Does the record get updated in the Access db? Is your connection string valid? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: The record does not get updated, the connection string is valid and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: What about the data types? I see that they are of type VarChar - is that what they are in your database (text)?

Comment: Changed them to Integers and nothing happened, pressing the submit button once does nothing, pressing it a second time however gives the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occured in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString propety. The connection's current state is open.`

Comment: what is `connect` ? You're going to want to use a `using` statement to dispose of your connection once you've executed your SQL statement(s)

Comment: I have updated the code in the post to show all of the code in the form.

Comment: I wouldn't initialize the `OleDbConnection` like that. Just try to use it in a `using` statement inside the code block where you execute the sql command

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? I've never used `using` before.

Comment: Let me link you to another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10375210/2679750) .. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Updated the code in the post to show off the using function, however nothing changed in the response.

Comment: Do you still get the exception?

Comment: One the second button push no I do not.

Comment: Check your table definition. It looks like your `SKU` field may not be defined as `Text`. You should be using a query parameter in your WHERE clause anyway. (There's no need to mix query parameters [good] *and* dynamic SQL [bad].)

Answer (score 1):

Your code to perform the update is *inside* the `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(units))` block, so if `units` actually has a value then the code will never be executed. It looks like you need an `else` after your error message.

Comment: I have amended the code fixing this issue, now I just receive a pop up saying "Microsoft JET Database Engine".

Comment: @iiAaronXiX `MessageBox.Show(expe.ToString());`

Comment: @iiAaronXiX - Don't bury new information in comments. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix the issue and get it to save to the database. Thank you for everyone's help and suggestions.

Here's the working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace InventoryManager
{
    public partial class frmAdjustment : Form
    {
        frmAmendStock _main;

        public string enteredSKU { get; set; }

        public frmAdjustment(frmAmendStock main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _main = main;
        }        

        private void frmAdjustment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = btnSubmit;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection())
            {

                connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Other\Documents\University Work\USB\Individual Project\Artefact\InventoryManager\InventoryManager\stock.mdb";
                connect.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE items SET Stock = @stock, Stock_Counted = @counted WHERE SKU LIKE '" +enteredSKU+"'", connect);
                string units = txtAmount.Text;

                    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(units))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct amount of units.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stock", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@counted", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;

                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("Stock Adjusted", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                                txtAmount.Clear();

                                connect.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception expe)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(expe.ToString());
                                connect.Close();
                            }
                      }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```