# How to open multiple Microsoft Access (mdb) files in C#?

Tags: c#, file, ms-access

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c), I figured out how open and connect to a single mdb file. 
At the moment I am doing:

```
String accessConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                                 Data Source=C:\MyMDB\MyMDBFile.mdb; 
                                 Persist Security Info = False; ";
using (OleDbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString))
      {
           ReadContent(); 
      }
```

But I want to open multiple files from the directory, basically I want to:

```
String[] mdbFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyMDB\", "*.mdb");
```

And use this in the `accessConnectionString`

I know it should be something like,

```
foreach (var filePath in mdbFiles)
        {
             accessConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" 
             + "Data Source=" + filePath + " Persist Security Info = False; ";
        }
```

But is this the only way to access multiple mdb files?

Comment: First, your code doesn't open anything and because you reset the variable accessConnectionString at every loop you end up with a connectionstring only for the last file in the folder. Second, the connection string serves as input to the OleDbConnection object and this object handles only one connection at a time. You need multiple OleDbConnection one for each file you intend to work with

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of these files and why you need them opened simultaneously?

Comment: have a List of connections, and do a foreach *.mdb, list.Add(new Oledbconnection(connectstring with that mdb in it)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have more clarity now!