# How to Open an database with the File.Open method

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with a button and a dataGridView, I know I can open my database with the OleDB connection, but my problem is that I may have to search where my database (a ".mdb" file) is on my computer.

Is there any way that with this button I open a File.Open (to search my database) and then show it on my datagridview ?

Comment: If you know the data structure of MDB, then yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: how may I search it (I'll add the filter only to read the .mdb files) and when I select it I already activate my query to do a `SELECT * FROM mydatabase` and show it on the datagridView

Comment: Use OleDB, it is easier, then re-inventing OleDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to connect the database with Data providers, not open it like a text file. This thread might be useful for you: [How to connect to a MS Access file (mdb) using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374808/how-to-connect-to-a-ms-access-file-mdb-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here you have an example:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean with 'File.Open', but you could make a `OpenFileDialog` where the user is able to select the file he wants to open. From this dialog you get a Filename which you can use in your connection string.

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "Database Files|*.mdb";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    string dbfile = dlg.FileName;
    string connectstring = string.format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}";Persist Security Info=False;, dbfile);

     using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectstring)) {
         //... do your database operations here
     }

}
```

Comment: saying "file.Open' I meant this situation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, you cannot directly open a db file with `File.Open` unless you know the internal structure of that file. That's what OleDb is here for. You would have to reimplement all those things yourself.